# Получить разные значения одной переменной из $_GET

Tags: php, form, get, checkbox

Задача банальная, но не пойму как сделать. Нужно сделать так, чтоб из списка элементов можно было пакетно удалить сразу несколько элементов. В форме

```html
<form name="del_id" action="delete.php" method="GET">
<input type="checkbox" name="del_id" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="del_id" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="del_id" value="3">
</form>
```

В адресной строке получаю, к примеру, **delete.php?del_id=2&del_id=3**
Но как из $_GET массива вытащить разные значения одной и той же переменной? Когда разные переменные - все понятно. Когда значение одно - то же все понятно. А здесь нужно как-то сосчитать и разобрать по переменным $_GET-массив и вставить в SQL-запрос. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: значение атрибутов name="" должны быть разными, ваш пример противоречит стандартам

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку с 'name', но сложность у меня именно с обработкой запроса - каким циклом её делать?

Answer (score 1):

`name="del_id[]"` чтобы записать переменные в массив и передать как в Вашем примере. И получив массив `$_GET['del_id'] = array('2', '3');` переделать обработку запроса

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку с 'name', но сложность у меня именно с обработкой запроса - каким циклом её делать?

Answer (score -1):

Решил вопрос с помощью цикла foreach.

Обработчик:

```html
if (isset($_GET['del_id'])) {$del_id = $_GET['del_id'];}

foreach ($del_id as $v) {
    $result = mysql_query ("DELETE FROM locality WHERE id='$v'");
}
```

Нехорошо только то, что каждое удаление идет отдельным запросом здесь. Но в целом проблема решена.

Comment: можно и одним запросом: `$str_id = implode (",", $_GET['del_id']); mysql_query ("DELETE FROM locality WHERE id IN (".$str_id.")");`